# How to add a custom RuleBasedClassifier after CalibratedClassifierCV to sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the `CalibratedClassifierCV` to be able to use `predict_proba` on the `LinearSVC`. Now I want to add a custom classifier to my pipeline, which assigns all predictions beneath a probability of 10% to the "Others" category. The rest of the predicted classes shall be put through without any change.

```py
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from custom_model import RuleBasedClassifier

pipeline_clf = Pipeline([
    ("MLClassifier", CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(C=0.6))),
    ("RuleBasedClassifier", RuleBasedClassifier())
])
```

However, if I try adding a custom Classifier to the sklearn pipeline, I get the following error message:

```py
   TypeError: All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement 
   fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 
   'CalibratedClassifierCV' doesn't
```

I do not know, how to change the `CalibratedClassifierCV` to pass through the result to the custom classifier.

Comment: Please add reproducible code sample with imports. It'll be easier to debug with a larger context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a custom transfomer like the following one.

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class ExtractProbsFromClassifier(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, clf):
        self.clf = clf
        self.feature_names_ = None

    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.clf.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return self.clf.predict_proba(X)

    def get_feature_names(self):
        if self.feature_names_ is None:
            prefix = np.full(len(self.clf.classes_), fill_value="Prob_", dtype="<U5")
            self.feature_names_ = np.core.defchararray.add(prefix, self.clf.classes_).tolist()
        return self.feature_names_
```

This can be used in a pipeline like this:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline([
  ("ExtractProbs", ExtractProbsFromClassifier(clf=CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(C=0.6))),
  ("RuleBasedClassifier", RuleBasedClassifier())
], verbose=True)
```